# Why this simple SFML app produce such high CPU usage?

Tags: sfml, vsync, cpu

I written the following SFML.NET app.
It  draw a single 128x128 sprite on the screen.

```
RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
window.SetVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

Texture texture = new Texture("test.jpg");    
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);

// Start the game loop
while (window.IsOpen())
{
    window.DispatchEvents();
    window.Clear();
    window.Draw(sprite);
    window.Display();
}
```

Since VSync is enabled, the number of FPS is capped to 60. I expect the program to use very little CPU, but under task manager it show me that is use about 50%  (two cores fully actually). Also it seems it use about 30% kernel time and the rest is user time.

The exact same application in SDL (just drawing a single sprite) use about 0% (regardless SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED is used or not).

EDIT : surprisingly, if I let the app run for a given amount of time (let's say 10-20 seconds, the CPU usage fall down to 0%). I manage to repeat this several times. That is really strange.

Comment: Couldn't you use a profiler to get a bit more insight?

Comment: It is possible that your video driver is not using VSYNC the way you think is working. Instead of waiting to draw each frame, the program is firing as fast as it possibly can on the thread frames and the driver is filtering out the excess while drawing exact 60FPS only. Try using a timer or other function to control your loop instead of VSYNC as that is driver dependant.

Comment: FRAPS is reporting 60fps. I have also put a counter inside the main loop : it is hit 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the "Threaded Optimisation" option to "Off" in the NVidia control panel totally fixes the problem (it was "Auto" by default). So this is a video card driver issue, not a SFML one. I don't know what this setting exactly do (must read about it)